# Python Flask API and AJAX

Tags: python, flask

This is an simple example **Python Flask API and AJAX** (code below), and I would like to get a solution:

*Response Headers - Content-type: application/json

Request Headers - Accept: application/json, text/plain

and the display in the browser itself to be as it is formatted in the index.html template (not json)*

*My question*:
*is it possible to do it all in python, (but the display in the browser to be the same but without Angular, React ... and how to do it?*

This is part of my Python of code, very simple:

```py
class Product(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "products"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(15),nullable=False)
    price = db.Column(db.Float(10,2),nullable=False)
    category = db.Column(db.String(10),nullable=False)
 
    def __init__(self, name, price, category):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.category = category
 
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.name}:{self.price}"

class ProductSchema(ma.Schema):
     class Meta:
          fields = ["id","name","price","category"]

product_schema = ProductSchema()
products_schema = ProductSchema(many=True)

@app.route("/ajaxSearchProducts",methods=["POST","GET"])
def ajaxSearchProducts():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        searchProduct = request.form['data4Search']
        if  searchProduct == '':
            data = Product.query.all()
        else:
            data = Product.query.filter(Product.name.like("%"+searchProduct + "%")).all()

        products = products_schema.dump(data)
        foundRows  = len(products)

        return jsonify({'dataResponse': render_template('newindex2.html', products=products, foundRows = foundRows) })

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('newindex1.html')
```

newindex1.html

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      function getData(data4Search) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "/ajaxSearchProducts",
          method: "POST",
          data: { data4Search: data4Search },
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
            $("#result").append(data.dataResponse);
          }
        });
      }
      $('#searchArticle').keyup(function () {
        var searchData = $(this).val();
        if (searchData.length >= 3 || searchData == '')
        {
          getData(searchData);
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <h1>Product List</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="search-box">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <h5>Search Artical Name</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <input type="text" name="searchArticle" id="searchArticle" class="form-control"
            placeholder="Search Artical Name ... min. 3 char. for search">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="result">
    </div>
  </div>
```

newindex2.html

```
<h3>{{foundRows}} Records Found</h3>
<table class="table" id="myTable">
    <thead style="background-color: brown;color: aliceblue;">
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Category</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for product in products %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ loop.index }}</td>
            <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
            <td>{{product.price}}</td>
            <td>{{product.category}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

this solution of mine partially answers my question 
***The only question remains***:
*can I get Json with only data in the Response tab (Inspect - Response) instead of Json which includes and table elements (last picture Inspect - Resposne)*?

 
If you have any other solution to my initial question, it is welcome!

You can see the results of this code change in the images below:

[List products - browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfgpN.png) 
[Inspect - Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rf1KI.png) 
[Inspect - Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbaYX.png) 
[Inspect - Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONm2W.png)

Comment: Any idea, any other solution, advice...?